# How to get data options from jquery multiple selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a selector `$(".status")` that returns multiple elements. I have data-options set on each of these elements.

```
$(".status").each(function (e) {
    e.data('options')
});
```

This gives me an error saying `undefined is not a function`.

If it helps I'm using Marionette, also tried `this.ui.status` hash array, but same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the first argument in `each` function is for index of element in matched selection.

> .each( function )
>   function
>   Type: Function( Integer index, Element element )
>   A function to execute for each matched element.
>   You need to use:

Thus you need to either pass e as second argument and index as first argument. Or, rather use  `this` to access current object

```
$(".status").each(function(e){
   alert($(this).data('options'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

[.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) is having 2 arguments, 1 the index of the current element, 2 the dom element reference of current element.

```
$(".status").each(function (i, e) {
    $(e).data('options')
});
```

Also you need access the jQuery wrapper to the element to call any jQuery methods on it by passing it to `jQuery`